# How to get content from tornado future object

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, tornado, future

I'm really confused by the tornado frame work and the 'future' object.
So I want to get a async response by making a http call
Code is:

```
class TestAsyncHttp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    @gen.coroutine
    def get_response(self, params)
        response = yield self._request(
            method='POST',
            endpoint='test'
            data=params
        )
        raise gen.Return(response)

    @gen.coroutine
    def _request(self, method, endpoint, data):
        url = self._make_url(endpoint) #this includes the port..
        headers = self._load_headers()
        request = httpclient.HTTPRequest(
            url,
            method=method,
            headers=header,
            body=json.dump(data)
        )
        response = yield self._http_client.fetch(request)
        raise gen.Return(response)
```

The thing is, after I finished this one, how can I test it?

I tried to write a scrip which contains...:

```
import json
with open('test/request.json') as json_file:
    request_json = json.loads(json_file.read())

def get_response():
    x = TestAsyncHttp()
    ret = yield x.get_response(request_json)
    body = ret.body
    print body['value']

get_response
```

But then I 'python "path-to-the-script"'
There's nothing output.
If I just stepped into the "python" environment, I got "future" object doesn't have **getitem**
..How can I get the content from a future..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`run_sync`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_sync) to run an async coroutine in a synchronous fashion:

```
def get_response():
    x = TestAsyncHttp()
    ret = IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda: x.get_response(request_json))
    body = ret.body
    print body['value']
```

The `lambda` is required here simply to pass the `request_json` parameter. If `get_response` took no arguments, you could instead do:

```
ret = IOLoop.current().run_sync(x.get_response)
```